# Ember app not reading API, using hapijs I believe my API is fine just an ember issue

Tags: ember.js, hapi.js

so I started building an app that uses ember and hapi to learn both.

I have pasted the snippets below but I also have both the server and ember app available in a repo here, https://github.com/jrutishauser/contactsApp if you are interested in viewing what I have there.

I have my hapi server showing the below from my sql server

```
{"data":[{"id":1,"first_name":"Joe","middle_initial":null,"last_name":"Smith","title":null,"phone_number":"(555) 111-2222","email":"jsmith@test.net","street_address":"123 Some Street","city":"Salt Lake City","state":"Utah","zip_code":"84111","created_at":1456988902625,"updated_at":1456988902625},{"id":2,"first_name":"John","middle_initial":null,"last_name":"Jones","title":null,"phone_number":"(555) 222-3333","email":"jjones@test.net","street_address":"1432 Another Street","city":"Montgomery","state":"Alabama","zip_code":"99291","created_at":1456988902625,"updated_at":1456988902625},{"id":3,"first_name":"Joe","middle_initial":null,"last_name":"Smith","title":null,"phone_number":"(555) 111-2222","email":"jsmith@test.net","street_address":"123 Some Street","city":"Salt Lake City","state":"Utah","zip_code":"84111","created_at":1457588539468,"updated_at":1457588539468},{"id":4,"first_name":"John","middle_initial":null,"last_name":"Jones","title":null,"phone_number":"(555) 222-3333","email":"jjones@test.net","street_address":"1432 Another Street","city":"Montgomery","state":"Alabama","zip_code":"99291","created_at":1457588539468,"updated_at":1457588539468}]}
```

at

http://localhost:3000/api/contacts

my ember app has these files below containing,

adapters/application.js,

```
  1 import DS from 'ember-data';
  3 export default DS.JSONAPIAdapter.extend({
  4   namespace: 'api',        
  5   host: 'http://localhost:3000'
  6 });
```

models/contact.js,

```
  1 import DS from 'ember-data';

  3 export default DS.Model.extend({
  5   firstName: DS.attr('string'),
  6   lastName: DS.attr('string'),
  7   middleInitial: DS.attr('string'),
  8   title: DS.attr('string'),
  9   phoneNumber: DS.attr('string'), 
  10   email: DS.attr('string'),
  11   streetAddress: DS.attr('string'),
  12   city: DS.attr('string'),
  13   state: DS.attr('string'),
  14   zipCode: DS.attr('string'),
  15   createdAt: DS.attr('date'),
  16   updatedAt: DS.attr('date')  
  17 });
```

routes/contacts.js

```
  1 import Ember from 'ember'; 
  2                            
  3 export default Ember.Route.extend({
  4     model: function(){     
  5         return this.store.findAll('contact');
  6     }                      
  7 });
```

I also set this up under serializers/application.js but dont think its necessary since I dont need to normalize anything

```
  1 import DS from 'ember-data';
  2 
  3 export default DS.JSONAPISerializer.extend({
  4   primaryKey: 'id',
  5   serializeId: function(id) {
  6     return id.toString();
  7   }
  8 });
```

templates/contacts.hbs

```
  1 <ul>  
  2   {{#each contact in model}}
  3       <li>{{#link-to 'contact' contact}}{{contact.firstName}}{{/link-to}}</li>
  4   {{/each}}
  5 </ul>  
  6 
  7 {{outlet}}
```

All Im expecting is the contacts route to just show the list currently from the api, I am not done with this yet and have been stuck here for some time.

the console errors I get are,

```
ember.debug.js:28590 Error while processing route: contacts.index Assertion Failed: You may not set `id` as an attribute on your model. Please remove any lines that look like: `id: DS.attr('<type>')` from (unknown mixin) Error: Assertion Failed: You may not set `id` as an attribute on your model. Please remove any lines that look like: `id: DS.attr('<type>')` from (unknown mixin)
```

and

```
Error: Assertion Failed: Encountered a resource object with an undefined type (resolved resource using contacts-app@serializer:application:)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Ember Data by default it uses the `JSONAPISerializer` to serialize and deserialize records.

The `JSONApiSerializer` supports the http://jsonapi.org/ spec.

For that to work you need to return the data from the server according to the `JSON API` spec or normalize the data in the serializer in your ember app.

You can look at the example in the Ember guides that explains this http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.JSONAPISerializer.html

You can also check plugins that implement the spec here http://jsonapi.org/implementations/#client-libraries-javascript. Looks like there is a plugin for the `hapi` framework (https://github.com/wraithgar/hapi-json-api) since you are using that it might help.

Comment: thanks for sharing these resources I will go through them when I get a chance today and hopefully find my mistake.

Comment: @imnothardcore Example the second error you get is because the spec states you need to define type for the model. So each contact should have in the response `type='contact'`. Also all attributes should be defined inside `attributes` hash in the response etc. In the link above from the ember guides you can see a bit better example how the payload should look like.

Comment: thanks, that solved all of my console errors and using the ember chrome plugin it appears I can see my array with 4 objects.  Looks like I just have an error on my ember model/template